# AWS S3 File Upload with VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, amazon-s3, file-upload

I am trying to use the sample code supplied by AWS to upload a file to S3 from a VB.net web application.  I converted the C# sample code to VB and have it contained in a separate file called UploadToS3.vb.  The issue I am running into is that I am lost on how to pass the file into the UploadToS3.vb file and have it uploaded.

On the frontend of the web application I'm using the following to select the file and submit:

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="lblUpload" runat="server" Text="UPLOAD"></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" /><br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Code Behind File:

```
Namespace Amazon.DocSamples.S3
Class UploadFileMPUHighLevelAPITest
    Private Const bucketName As String = "webapp.company.com"
    Private Const keyName As String = "*** provide a name for the uploaded object ***"
    Private Const filePath As String = "*** provide the full path name of the file to upload ***"
    Private Shared ReadOnly bucketRegion As RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USEast1
    Private Shared s3Client As IAmazonS3

    Public Shared Sub Main()
        s3Client = New AmazonS3Client(bucketRegion)
        UploadFileAsync().Wait()
    End Sub

    Private Shared Async Function UploadFileAsync() As Task
        Try
            Dim fileTransferUtility = New TransferUtility(s3Client)
            Await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(filePath, bucketName)
            Console.WriteLine("Upload 1 completed")
            Await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(filePath, bucketName, keyName)
            Console.WriteLine("Upload 2 completed")

            Using fileToUpload = New FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
                Await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(fileToUpload, bucketName, keyName)
            End Using

            Console.WriteLine("Upload 3 completed")
        Catch e As AmazonS3Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Error encountered on server. Message:'{0}' when writing an object", e.Message)
        Catch e As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Unknown encountered on server. Message:'{0}' when writing an object", e.Message)
        End Try
    End Function
End Class
End Namespace
```

Sample Code From AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLuploadFileDotNet.html

**More specific questions:**
What does the value for "filepath" look like?  Simply the name of the folder in the S3 bucket?
Is the Private Const keyname as string... needed if the name of the uploaded file is used by default?
What do I put in the submit button click event to call the S3 upload?

**Any help would be greatly appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

No, I think the file path is the path of the file where the function **UploadAsync** is going to get the file to upload it to S3.

The way you can do this is, the vb app need to be in a server in a hosting, well when you do upload i think you need to save the file to a temporal folder in your server and then with that oath use the S3 function **UploadAsync** to upload the file to S3.

Comment: Yes this appears to be correct.  The filepath is the path and file name that should be uploaded to S3.  I currently have it setup to upload the file to the server in an uploads directory. ex. "C:\uploads\file.pdf"  Then the UploadAsync takes the file from this uploads folder and uploads it to S3.  Is there a better way that doesn't store it temporarily on the server?  This method would be doubling the required bandwidth by sending the file to the server and then the server sending it to S3.

Comment: yes maybe but should be done manually with the CLI from your PC, you can do this from your PC and the path will be your local path but when you do this with  a software, there is no other way than upload the file to the server.